# Hibernate @OneToMany & @OneToOne associations to non-nullable entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have the following problem. I want to model a `UserProfile` which may have multiple `UserEmail`s. One of those emails is the primary email of the profile and I want to enforce that there has to be a primary email (not `null`).

I have setup the entities like so:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile {
    
   @NotNull
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "primary_user_email_id", nullable = false)
   private UserEmail primaryEmail;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userProfile", orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<UserEmail> emails;

   // other fields for profile details e.g. username, id ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_email")
public class UserEmail {
    
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_profile_id", nullable = false)
   private UserProfile userProfile;

   // other fields for email details e.g. address, isConfirmed, id ...
}
```

I have not-`nullable` constraints on the database columns `user_profile.primary_user_email_id` & `user_email.user_profile_id` along with foreign key constraints.

This setup works fine if I remove the not-`nullable` constraint from the column `primary_user_email_id` (along with the `@NotNull` annotation and the `nullable` property of `@JoinColumn`). So I can just create new `UserProfile`s with new `UserEmail`s added to the list of `email`s and persist the profile. After that I can set one of the emails as the primary email and update the profile.

However, I would like to keep the database constraints so I can enforce that there has to be a primary email. I think this might not be possible because if I try persisting everything at once (new profil with new primary email which is also in the list of emails) there are always errors that the non-`nullable` constraint is being violated because of the transient entity.

Is there a way to enforce a non-nullable column for the `primaryEmail`? Maybe there is a better way to model this use case?

Answer (score 0):

At least some databases like Postgres or Oracle support deferred constraints for this use case. They are not enforced until commit time, so you can prepare both rows and commit them together.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. Unfortunately I want to support MySQL and deferrable constraints don't seem to be supported for MySQL.